# creating new record in store with hasMany relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Using the following model and store, I can successfully load data using FIXTURES as shown below.

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
   itemName: DS.attr('string'),
   strategy: DS.belongsTo('strat')
});

App.Strat = DS.Model.extend({
    stratName: DS.attr('string'),
    items: DS.hasMany('item',{async:true})

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter
});

App.StratLeg.FIXTURES =
[
{id: 1, itemName: 'I1', strategy: 1},
{id: 2, itemName: 'I2', strategy: 2},
{id: 3, itemName: 'l3', strategy: 2},
];

App.Strat.FIXTURES =
[
{id: 1, stratName: 's1', items: [1]},
{id: 2, stratName: 's2', items: [2,3]}
];
```

---

But when I tried to add a new record using javascript, I ran into all sorts of errors.  Following the examples in the EmberData-API documention for DS.store, I tried:

```
var pushData = {
  strat: [{id: 100, stratName: "s5", items: [101]}],
    item: [{id: 101, itemName: "I5", strategy: 100}]};

this.store.push ('strat', pushData);
```

---

This generated the following error:

"you must include an 'id' in a hash passed to 'push'.

I've also tried various incarnations of store.createRecord, which resulted in different errors.

What's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on if you are in the latest version of ember data, you can use pushPayload and push them in this format (not the pluralized format of the keys)

```
 var pushData = {
     strats: [{id: 100, stratName: "s5", items: [101]}],
     items: [{id: 101, itemName: "I5", strategy: 100}]
 };

 store.pushPayload('strat', pushData);
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OHUcIx/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried your suggestion, and got the following error: TypeError: serializer.pushPayload is not a function.  I'm using ember-data-beta-3.js.

Comment: It looks like it is working to me, I included a working example.

Comment: Where are you trying to do it?